Get pointer to non-virtual member function code bytes C++
Say I have some class:
class A
{
  double f(int x);
};

I want to get a void* to the bytes in the __TEXT segment that represent the implementation of the member function A::f. I don't want to use the pointer as a function pointer to call the function, I just want to inspect the bytes representing the machine code. Is there a good way to do this? Ideally without having to use any runtime calls. I need to inspect the bytes at runtime.
I want to achieve something like:
int32_t* bytesOfFunc = (get address of A::f);
int32_t instruction = bytesOfFunc[0];
if(instruction == OP_CODE_1)
{
   // Do something
}

I am using clang and LLVM.
I have found a way and adding it here so others can find it. It works on 64-bit iOS with clang and LLVM for non-virtual member functions on but it is not portable. I will also be writing tests to ensure these point to the correct spot and would recommend you do the same if you do this.
Basically you can get around the compiler error of converting a pointer to member to a void* if you throw it into an array first and then cast the array and then the element of the array.
decltype(&A::f) pointerAsArray[1];
pointerAsArray[0] = &A::f;
void* rawPointerBox = pointerAsArray;
void* rawPointer = (void*)((uint64_t*)rawPointerBox)[0];

Again, this is not portable, as your compiler may not treat pointers to non-virtual members as function pointers with an implicit this argument.

Not without digging into clang internals to find out how "pointer to member" is actually implemented, and then using that knowledge to find the address of the code. However, an easier way would be to use the mangled name, and a line of assembler code to give you the value of that symbol... that would probably be what I'd try first.

I was thinking of using the mangled name, but all the symbols will be stripped by runtime so looking through the symbol table isn't an option here.

@GarriganStafford I'm not suggesting to look into the symbol table. As an example -- and I've never used x86 assembler so I don't know what the usual syntax would be -- if the mangled symbol is "_ZFooBarX173", I'd add simply add a line of assembler like ".DATA: ULONG _MyAddress=_ZFooBarX173" to create a data item "MyAddress" with the address you're looking for. Of course, the actual assembler line will look very different.

Do you want this at runtime, or at compile time?  At compile time, you can use -S.

Here's a "proof of concept" type of thing for my assembler idea...
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    double bar(int x)
    {
        return x*5;
    }
};

asm("\t.global test\n"
    "\t.data\n"
    "\t.align  2\n"
    "\t.type   test, %object\n"
#if __SIZEOF_POINTER__ == 8
    "\t.size   test, 8\n"
    "test:\n"
    "\t.8byte   _ZN3Foo3barEi\n"
#elif __SIZEOF_POINTER__ == 4
    "\t.size   test, 4\n"
    "test:\n"
    "\t.4byte   _ZN3Foo3barEi\n"
#else
#error fix me
#endif
    "\t.text\n");

extern void* test;

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo{}.bar(2) << '\n';
    std::cout << test << '\n';
    std::cout << ((double(*)(void*,int))test)(nullptr, 3) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Note: the above works on g++, x64_64 and aarch64. I don't have a clang, and I don't have other CPUs...
stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ uname -m; g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
aarch64
10
0x107e0
15

stieber@debian:~$ uname -m; g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
x86_64
10
0x55ac1ee29286
15

I'm reasonably positive that the pointer does point to the code, since with the crazy casting I can even call it to obtain the correct result...
When I add virtual, it still works.
Highly not-portable, of course. Also, for this to work, you can only access functions that you already know beforehand, and you have to lookup the mangled name externally as well -- I don't think there's a way to create the asm-string at compiletime from a more readable function name.
Note: calling a member function like this was just lucky: at least on this compiler, passing the invisible this seems to follow the same rules as normal parameters. This might not work on every compiler, of course -- but I just wanted to do it to "prove" that I'm actually getting the correct pointer, and calling it seemed to be the best choice for that.
Well, enough fun for today, I guess :-) Mind you, I see this kind of stuff anywhere, and if hierarchy allows it, the guy WILL have some serious explaining to do :-)
